# Driving multiple stepper motors

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, multiplexer

During the last days I've been working on driving multiple stepper motors (28BYJ-48 – 5V) with SparkCore and Stepper.h arduino library. I'm trying to drive some stepper motors, but without having to move them at the same time. I mean, stepper1 moves 100 steps, once finished, stepper2 moves 30 steps, and so on.

In the explanation I'll use two steppers.

The point is that I have some doubts of how to do it using the less ICs and easier as possible.

## Option 1 (it works)

The first try was using a **CD54/74HC137** (3-to-8 Line Decoder Demultiplexer with address Latches) and a **CD4508B** ( CMOS Dual 4-Bit Latch).

### Workflow:

Stepper.h library is configured to work with D0-D3 pins.

- D0 to D3 pins are connected in series to both **CD4508B** input pins (dual latch).
- The decoder enables or disables the input pins of **CD4508B**, in order to choose the stepper that I want to move.
- In Stepper.cpp library, each time that sends an step, I enable the two strobes of the **CD4508B**.
- The outputs of **CD4508B** are connected to **ULN2003A**  IC (darlington transistor array) that will drive the stepper.

So, every CD4508B can drive 2 stepper motors. All CD4508B input ports recieve the same inputs and the same strobe (they are in series) and using the demultiplexer I enable/disable one or the other input port and I move one or the other stepper.

I've tried it and works perfect, but I think that it could be easier and could be done without CD4508B. So here is my second option.

## Option 2

[image]

I'm thinking in connecting directly D0-D3 to both **ULN2003A** (or similiars) input in series and using the **CD74HC237** demultiplexer enable/disable the ULN2003A.

The point is that ULN2003A has not enable/disable pin so I'm afraid it won't be so easy. I've found a darlington transistor array IC with a latch that could do it well: [TLC59213](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59213.pdf)

I've phoned some electronic shops and do not have it. They said it's a strange IC.

So, what to do you think is the best choice? I think that option2 could do the job, but the TLC59213 is not easy to find, perhaps another IC that could do it as well. Any suggestions will help.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the easiest choice would be to just use 4 different I/O pins and adapt the library. Most of the code will be exactly the same. All that is needed is to make it work with 2 (or more) stepper motors. Any reason you wouldn't want to take this route?

Comment: this question is related to the OP's similar question asked on May 4, and several comments and answers are given there : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109123/any-ic-similar-to-uln2003a-with-latch-or-enable-disable/109146#109146

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot simpler both in terms of circuitry and software if you use a dedicated stepper driver, eg. A4988 available in cheap bread-board friendly carriers. The A4988 has a proper H-bridge capable of up to 2A per coil and takes care of dead-timing and micro-stepping.

Answer (score -2):

Use a mosfet to enable a uln.  Use 7 pins to control 15 steppers motors with 22pins. 4 to count up, 3 to count down. (1 is shared).  So you can only move motors 4 steps at a time.  7 pins plus 1 pin per motor.  Each uln can only run 1 motor so you lose 3 Darlington arrays on a uln2003.

I'll do a YouTube video if you subscribe to my channel "theRainHarvester".

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. From the ["What kind of behavior is expected of users?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) portion of the help page: "**Avoid overt self-promotion.** *The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam.*" This answer could be improved with a schematic. Or if you're going to do a video, do it and then post the link in the answer. If it's any good you might get a few extra subs, as opposed to getting down votes here.